# I want to select record multiple key with like

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select record from table with key.My code is working but it's not select all record regarding Php and Mysql it select only PHP,Mysql record. 
My code is

```
  $skill=PHP,Mysql;

  mysql_query("select * from tablename(skill) where fieldname(key) like '%$skill%'");
```

Comment: Have you tried to combine them with the AND keyword?

Comment: Do you want to have the records with "php","mysql",combination of php and mysql

Comment: first enclose your variable in single or double quotes like $skill="PHP,Mysql"; then try it

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

```
mysql_query("select * from skill where (key like '%PHP%' OR key like '%Mysql%')");
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have comma separated values in $skill variable like operator will not work correctly, try using following query

```
select * from skill where FIND_IN_SET(keyn,'$skill')
```

Demo sql fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/181c74/5

Answer (score 0):

```
$skill="PHP,Mysql";

mysql_query("select * from skill where key like '%$skill%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to search for records that contain "PHP", "MySQL", or both. What you're doing is searching for the exact string of "PHP,MySQL".

A quick and dirty solution would be to turn $skill into an array that is split on the commas and then perform the search for each term using the OR keyword.

For example:

```
$skill = array("PHP", "MySQL");
$query = "select * from tablename(skill) where ";
foreach ($skil in $skill)
  $query . "fieldname(key) like '%$skil%' OR ";
//code to remove the OR at the very end
```

Comment: Actually i have two tables first student and second employer.First i run the query $student=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from student)); after that i keep the skill in variable $skill=student['skill'];

Comment: Suppose in the varible $skill=PHP,Mysql this record and it's according i have to select all the record related with php and mysql from table employer please help me

Comment: mysql_query("select * from employer where job_keyskills like '%$skill%'

Comment: @shakti, I think you can use the same idea in this case. You could try to split $skill into an array based on the commas. $query would start with `"SELECT * FROM employer WHERE "` and you would concatenate `"job_keyskills LIKE '%$singleSkill%' OR "` for each skill. Again, this is only a quick, dirty, and naive solution to your problem. For almost all cases where you want to implement any kind of smart searching, you will have to make your application do some work to format the search topic and execute a custom query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` into your Query

```
select * from `skills` WHERE skillslist in ('Php','Javascript')
```

Run demo [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a664/2/0)